# Concrete Mathematics - 2.5 Method 5 Summation of $k^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

> $$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2  =  \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=j}^n k$$

This equation was given in book *Concrete Mathematics : A Foundation for Computer Science* Page 46 under Method 5: Expand and contract.

In book author jumped from single sum to double sum but how he derived the double sum(using summation properties) I am unable to get it.

Explain in detail please.

Answer (score 4):

I'll illustrate by calculating the right-hand-side expression with $n=5$. So we have an expression that runs from $j=1$ to $5$ like so:
$$
\begin{array}{crrrrrr}
j= 1 \Rightarrow & 1 &+ 2 &+3 &+4 &+5 \\
j= 2 \Rightarrow &  &  2 &+3 &+4 &+5 \\
j= 3 \Rightarrow &  &   &3 &+4 &+5 \\
j= 4 \Rightarrow &  &   & &4 &+5 \\
j= 5 \Rightarrow &  &   & & &5 \\
\end{array}
$$
what is the sum of all these rows? We have one $1$, two $2$'s, three $3$'s, four $4$'s and five $5$'s. So the sum is
$$
1\times 1 + 2\times 2 + 3\times 3 + 4\times 4 + 5\times 5
$$
which can also be written as
$$
\sum_{k=1}^5 k^2
$$

Comment: That I figured it out but I want to get from LHS to RHS. Anyway for thanks for help :)

Comment: @Utkrisht Why not just reverse the process described here then?

Answer (score 1):

One way to look at it is like this: note that $k=1+1+\cdots+1$  ($k$ times),
so $\displaystyle k=\sum_{j=1}^k 1$, and then
$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n kk=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^k k
=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=j}^n k$

where the last step is the standard switching of the order of summation.